How can I use a layout in my custom 404 page?
I'm using Nuxt 3 in one of my projects and have created a 404 page for it. I have two layouts in the project. My default layout (default.vue) includes general components like the footer and header. In my custom 404 page, I want to use the default layout (default.vue).
However, when I define my 404 component as shown below:
<script setup>
    const error = useError();

    console.log({error})

    const handleError = () => {
        clearError({
            redirect: '/',
        });
    };
</script>

<template>
    <NuxtLayout>
        <div class="prose">
            <h1>Dang</h1>
            <p>
                <strong>{{ error.message }}</strong>
            </p>
            <p>It looks like something broke.</p>
            <p>Sorry about that.</p>
            <p>
                Go back to your 
                <a @click="handleError">
                dashboard.
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
    </NuxtLayout>
</template>

I get an error due to a prop used in my header component.

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'modeCheckout')

Here is my codes:
layouts/default.vue
<script setup>
  import {inject,watch} from 'vue';
  const { alert, setAlert } = inject('alert')
</script>


<template>
  <div class="page-wrapper">
    <div class="content-wrapper" >
      <Alert :alert="alert"/>
      <AppBar/>
      <div class="main-wrapper">
        <slot></slot>
      </div>
      <WebsiteFooter/>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<style lang="scss">
.page-wrapper{
  @include d-flex(row,flex-start,flex-start);
  min-height: 100%;
  .content-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    .main-wrapper{
      margin-top: 10px;
      border-radius: 4px;
      padding: 16px;
    }
  }
}
</style>

AppBar.vue
<script setup>
  import {ref,inject} from 'vue';
  const props = defineProps({
    modeCheckout:{type:Boolean,default:false}
  })

  const isClickedHamMenu = ref(false);
  const {basketItemCount} = inject('basketItemCount')

  const toggleMenu = () =>{
    isClickedHamMenu.value = !isClickedHamMenu.value
    let menu = document.querySelector('.menu-wrapper');

    if(isClickedHamMenu.value){
      menu.classList.add('slide-menu-ttb');
      if(menu.classList.contains('slide-menu-btt')){
        menu.classList.remove('slide-menu-btt')
      }
    }
    else{
      menu.classList.add('slide-menu-btt');
      if(menu.classList.contains('slide-menu-ttb')){
        menu.classList.remove('slide-menu-ttb')
      }
      setTimeout(()=>{
        menu.classList.remove('slide-menu-btt');
      },150)
    }
  }
</script>
<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="app-bar-wrapper p10">
      <NuxtLink class="logo-wrapper" to="/">
        <img src="/logo.png" alt="Artisan">
      </NuxtLink>
      <div v-if="!props.modeCheckout" class="search-wrapper">
        <Icon name="mdi:magnify" color="black" size="24"/>
        <input type="text" autocomplete="off" spellcheck="false" placeholder="Search">
      </div>
      <div class="app-bar-actions">
        <div v-if="!props.modeCheckout" :class="['hamburger-wrapper', isClickedHamMenu ? 'close' : '']" @click="toggleMenu">
          <span class="child-1"></span>
          <span class="child-2"></span>
          <span class="child-3"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
          <Button
            icon="mdi:account"
            fontSize="24px"
            fontColor="#000"
            text
            hoveredBackground="transparent"
            background="transparent"
            hoveredColor="#000"
            padding="0"
          />
        </div>
        <NuxtLink to="/cart" class="icon-wrapper">
          <Button
            icon="mdi:cart-outline"
            fontSize="24px"
            fontColor="#000"
            text
            hoveredBackground="transparent"
            background="transparent"
            hoveredColor="#000"
            padding="0"
          />
          <div  v-if="basketItemCount>0" class="cart-item-count">
            {{basketItemCount}}
          </div>
        </NuxtLink>
      </div>
    </div>
    <Menu v-if="!props.modeCheckout"/>
  </div>
</template>

App.vue
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue'
  const alert = ref({});
  const basketItemCount = ref(0)
  const route = useRoute()

  const setAlert = obj => {
    alert.value = obj;
  }

  const setBasketItemCount = () =>{
    basketItemCount.value = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('basket-items'))?.reduce((a,b)=>a+b.quantity,0) || 0
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    setBasketItemCount();
  })

  provide('basketItemCount',{basketItemCount,setBasketItemCount})
  provide('alert', {alert,setAlert});
</script>

<template>
  <NuxtLayout>
    <NuxtPage />
  </NuxtLayout>
</template>


Please, provide a way to reproduce, it needs to be debugged. Currently only you do this. It seems unlikely that posted code could cause this error because it presumes that props is undefined, which cannot happen under normal circumstances, you can check that it's an object, make sure that are no errors beside it that could prevent AppBar from being instantiated normally

In Nuxt 3, you can create a custom error page with error.vue at the root of your project. To use the components from your default layout on the 404 error page, you can conditionally render them within error.vue based on the error code.
Here's an example setup:
Create or edit error.vue in the root of your project.
Render your default layout components like Header and Footer.
Example of error.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <Header />
    <div>
      <h1 v-if="is404">Page Not Found</h1>
      <p v-if="is404">The page you are looking for does not exist.</p>
      <p v-else>Oops! Something went wrong.</p>
    </div>
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import Header from '~/components/Header.vue'
import Footer from '~/components/Footer.vue'
import { computed } from 'vue'

const { error } = defineProps({ error: Object })
const is404 = computed(() => error?.statusCode === 404)
</script>

